# How to "make" lua module from source code?

Tags: build, lua, makefile

Ok, I'm completly new to all this "download and build (make, install, make-install and so on)", I'm trying understand, but it seems to me, I dont have enough expierence with all of this stuff.

I'm trying to build (or make, or install, I'm very confused) [this](https://github.com/kieselsteini/lua-struct) module for my first lua script.

So how do I build (make, install, or whatever) this modue for my system (Windows 7)?

Installation section says

> Installation
>
> Need lua 5.2, then just "make" it.

What do they want me to do? I can see this "source-to-make" everywhere, but I really don't understand what should I do, it's like obvious to everyone so there's no good step-by-step explanation.

Comment: Using Windows makes this more complicated. On non-Windows machines it would be as simple as installing the lua 5.2 package for your system, the lua 5.2 development headers, a C compiler, and the `make` tool. All of which should be fairly simple to do. On Windows that is more complicated and I'm not sure that module is set up to build on Windows. You might be better off using one of the half-dozen or so such modules that you can find around. For example the `struct` or `vstruct` modules available in [`LuaDist`](http://luadist.org/).

Comment: @EtanReisner so [this](https://github.com/Neopallium/lua-pb#design) isn't crossplatform as it uses struct I assume?

Comment: The struct there isn't the struct you found I don't think. I believe the struct there is the one packaged in luarocks which is also the one packaged in luadist. Things packaged as rocks should, I believe, generally only depend on other rocks.